# How to convert base64 images to Url images when using summer note text editor in Laravel inside controller?

Tags: laravel, summernote

I am trying to use image url instead of base64. i kindof figured a way how to get images out of the editor and save it inside the directory, but i am trying to insert it into database. i get this error.

Object of class DOMElement could not be converted to string

below i have added the store function inside my controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //
    $data = $request->all();

    if (!$request->has('published')) {
        $data['published'] = 0;
    } else {
        $data['published'] = 1;
    }

    if (!$request->has('featured')) {
        $data['featured'] = 0;
    } else {
        $data['featured'] = 1;
    }

    $img = null;
    if ($request->hasfile('title_img')) {

        $image = $request->file('title_img');
        $name = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $image->move(public_path() . '/uploads/blogs/', $name);
        $img = '/uploads/blogs/' . $name;
    }

    /* summernote */

    $detail=$data['description'];
    $dom = new \DomDocument();
    $dom->loadHtml($detail, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);    
    $images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');

    foreach($images as $k => $img){
        $data = $img->getAttribute('src');
        list($type, $data) = explode(';', $data);
        list(, $data)      = explode(',', $data);
        $data = base64_decode($data);
        $image_name= "/uploads/summernote/" . time().$k.'.jpeg';
        $path = public_path() . $image_name;
        file_put_contents($path, $data);
        $img->removeAttribute('src');
        $img->setAttribute('src', $image_name);
    }

    $detail = $dom->saveHTML();

    /* summernote */

    $data['title_img'] = $img;
    $data['user_id'] = auth()->user()->id;
    $title = $data['title'];
    $data['slug'] = Str::slug($title);

    auth()->user()->posts()->create($data);

    return Redirect::route('admin.blog.index')->withSuccess('Whoopie!! New Blog Added!');
}
```

I hope i can get some help regarding this. Thanks in advance

Comment: herein lies the problem `$data['title_img'] = $img;` $img is a DOM object. Perhaps you want to save the image url named $path?

Comment: @djunehor i changed it but i still got an error. illegal string offset title _img

Comment: @djunehor i found a solution for it, thanks to you as a matter of fact. ive been using the same variable to perform two different task. thank you for the eye opener